# Take substring from a regex capture group

Tags: c++, regex

I have this piece of C++ code:

```
std::string s ("%r34 = add i32 %r33, 1\n");
std::regex e ("\\b(r)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "r"
std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"r$2");
```

The output I get is:

```
%r34 = add i32 %r33, 1
```

My first question is there a way to remove the last character in the capture group `$2` to get the desired output of:

```
%r3 = add i32 %r3, 1
```

Second question: how can I find words starting with "%" instead of "r" as the following line doesn't work while still using the same logic as before:

```
std::regex e ("\\b(%)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "%"
```

Comment: For the first question, try `\\b(r)(\S*)\S`. As to the second question, it depends on what you consider a "word starting with %".

Comment: @41686d6564 any word starting with the character  % like %r34 or %r33. the  \\b(r)(\S*)\S doesn't find any matches :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape `\S`. It should be `\\b(r)(\\S*)\\S`. Note, however, that this will remove the comma after "33". Depending on your requirements, you might want to exclude commas as well: `\\b(r)([^\\s,]*)[^\\s,]`. Or if "r" is always followed by digits, you could just use `\\b(r)(\\d*)\\d`.

Comment: About your second question: Again, what _exactly_ do you consider a word? Does the '%' character have to be either at the beginning of the string or preceded by a whitespace exclusively?

Comment: thanks, exactly what I wanted for the first question :)..regarding the % has to be at the beginning of the string not necessarly preceded by a space

Comment: You probably want to use `(^|\\s)%r(\\d*)\\d`, and substitute with `$1%r$2`.

Comment: I've summarized the comments into an answer with online demos.

Comment: perfect :) ...thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the second last digit after 'r', you may use:

```
\\b(r)(\\d*)\\d
```

...and substitute with:

```
r$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQBYBD/1) - [C++ demo](https://rextester.com/UPLK55269)

If the chars that follow 'r' are not necessarily digits but you want to exclude the comma, you may use the following instead:

```
\\b(r)([^\\s,]*)[^\\s,]
```

To match only if 'r' is preceded by '%', use:

```
(^|\\s)%r(\\d*)\\d
```

And substitute with:

```
$1%r$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/91bCfT/1) - [C++ demo](https://rextester.com/LQZFJO14819)

Comment: Raw string might simplify regex: `R"(\b(r)(\d*)\d)"`